# how to convert char * to char[] in kernel mode

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

This is my linux kernel code
    When i try to set val of char* name to a field in my struct, i get null 
    The value in stuct is always null, however if i explicitly set person->key_day = "11"; I dont get the null value. I somehow want to get value from char *day and char *name to be assigned to person->key_day and person->value_name . Kindly Help

```
     typedef struct _birthday {
     char *key_day;
     char *value_name;
        struct list_head list;
    }birthday;

    birthday *person;

    /* Declare and init the head of the linked list. */

    LIST_HEAD(birthday_list);

    void mymap(char *day , char *name)
    {

            /* Request malloc to the kernel. */
            person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);

            /* Assign value to the struct. */
            person->key_day =  day;
            person->value_name = name;

            /* Init the list within the struct. */
            INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);

            /* Add this struct to the tail of the list. */
            list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);

            //This print statement gives me null value.
            printk("\n New Entry %s , %s" , person->key_day , person->value_name );
    }
```

Comment: This is more of a C question, not Linux kernel specific.  Why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: I'm using a linked list in my program, a link list of struct.

Comment: I have editted my question, with the actual code

Comment: You have allocated struct birthday, but that struct includes pointers to char arrays.  You have to malloc the memory that will be assigned to those pointers, then copy the data into that allocated memory and assign it to the pointers.

Comment: Thanks peter, can u kindly actually show me a small eg code.. so that i get an idea

Comment: For example, try this person->value_name = kmalloc(MAX_NAME_LEN, GFP_KERNEL) then strcpy() the name into it.  Do the same with key_day.